# Does Virtual Memory expand and contract or does it only expand in Windows 11

Tags: memory, windows-11, virtual-memory, memory-management

What makes the virtual memory expand and what makes virtual memory contract, if possible?

Trying to understand the uses of virtual memory and what makes it expand and contract in Windows 11

Comment: In which operating system?

Comment: @squillman Windows 11

Comment: are you asking about the size of the pagefile, or about the amount of it that contains page data at any given time?

Comment: @FrankThomas both

Comment: The pagefile (aka swap) (and its contents) should not be called "*virtual memory*". Such a conflation leads to odd questions like your title, and various misunderstandings. See https://superuser.com/questions/748743/what-is-the-difference-between-virtual-memory-and-built-in-memory-ram/748776#748776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual memory is usually pre-allocated and contiguous on
the disk, as it needs to be fast.

Under Windows, the size of virtual memory is defined via the
settings of Initial and Maximum. Changing this definition causes
the page-file to be reallocated on the disk to the specified
Initial size after a reboot.

If more virtual memory was required than is allocated, the
page-file may need to be increased, but it cannot be
reallocated on the disk to a bigger size because it already
contains data, so extensions are added to it which might not
be contiguous.

Once Windows is rebooted, its size returns to the Initial
size, but not immediately. Windows will keep the extended
page-file for some time, and will shrink it back to the
Initial size when it decides that a larger file is no
longer required.

For a user testimony, see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1829884/8672).

Comment: Alright, does it shrink when its automatically managed by Windows? also, how long is could "sometime" be, estimate?

Comment: It cannot shrink while Windows is running, since this will require finding out which parts of it contain data and which don't. Windows takes the simpler solution of increasing it when running, but reducing it only after a reboot, meaning when no jobs are running that can use any part of it. The algorithm behind the "how long" part is not documented, since Microsoft keeps the option of changing it in future Windows versions without notice. We don't know if this is by the number of boots or by the elapsed time.

Comment: Alright, will it still have a chance of adjusting while in sleep or only rebooting does it?

Comment: Sleep keeps all the memory data of Windows, so the computer will wake up to the exact same state, which also includes any swapped memory. So sleep is not enough, a reboot is required.

Comment: alright, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, it's up to the user. The *default* on install has been to allow the *Initial size* and *Maximum size* to differ, so pagefile.sys continually grows and shrinks.

Personally, I [prefer to set](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-virtual-memory-size-windows-10) the pagefile.sys to a *constant* size to reduce fragmentation by setting *Initial size* and *Maximum size* to the same value.

And then there is [swapfile.sys](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/hiberfil-pagefile-swapfile-sys-windows), which I believe is set to a *fixed* size.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at those settings.